# AutoHotKey: Send a button when another is held down, and after released

Tags: mouse, autohotkey

in AutoHotKey
I want to write a script that will press a button once when the right mouse button is held
and press another once its released.

I tried writing something (I used numpad0 instead of mousebutton)

```
Numpad0::
Send {d}

Numpad0 Up::
Send {u}
```

but, it keeps sending **du** all the time, instead of just **d** and a final **u**.

why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're putting your hotkey command on a different line to where the hotkey is declared you need to use a `return` statement to end it:

```
Numpad0::
Send {d}
return

Numpad0 Up::
Send {u}
return
```

You can also just declare each hotkey on one line without a `return` if you're not trying to do too much:

```
Numpad0:: Send {d}
Numpad0 Up:: Send {u}
```